# Lazy loader suddenly stopped working. Images not showing at all

Tags: javascript, html, image, lazy-loading

I've been using the same lazy loading script for years and after checking out my blog today, it's suddenly not working, no images are showing at all. I know it's the script because if I just put a basic image tag in, it works fine.

Honestly, the JS file is a mess as most of it is minified and I can't pick out just the lazyloader script. JS file is situated at: 
https://helloarchie-helloarchie.netdna-ssl.com/themes/tootsweet/js/cbpHorizontalSlideOutMenu.min.js

Example URL where images should display (All images at top ARE working, but nothing underneath 'Headers-' etc. near bottom of page, because those are set to lazyload): https://helloarchie.co/design/

Here's the HTML I've always used to display image:

```
<img class="one img-responsive" alt="" data-src="https://helloarchie-helloarchie.netdna-ssl.com/img/rapeseed-field/family-two-young-brothers- yellow-seed-field-photoshoot-bobochoses-filemonkid-mum-nan-play-flowers- jump6.jpg" src="https://helloarchie-helloarchie.netdna-ssl.com/img/grey.gif" />
<noscript><img class="image-asset" src="https://helloarchie-helloarchie.netdna-ssl.com/img/rapeseed-field/family-two-young-brothers-yellow-seed-field-photoshoot-bobochoses-filemonkid-mum-nan-play-flowers-jump6.jpg" alt=""></noscript>
```

It's a total nightmare as I have thousands of images on my blog and I'd have to manually configure each one if I can't get this working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Might be silly, but there is an additional space in your `data-src` (first line) `https://helloarchie- helloarchie.net...` should be probably `https://helloarchie-helloarchie.net..."` instead according to your img src. Try fixing your data src to see if it loads correctly then

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but that's not the case on my site. That's just a mistake entering it here.

Comment: The example you gave works fine on my pc...

Comment: Not for me too @GolezTrol

Comment: Really? Still not working on my Chrome or Safari desktop and not on my phone either. It might be a bit confusing, some images are working on the page because they're not set to lazy load, there should be large images amongst the text but they're not loading at all for me.

Comment: I don't know why your script isn't working. But you could use other lazy loading libraries, like [jQuery Lazy](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy). It will make things work again without changes on your image tags.